# How to run puppeteer instances in parallel

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, puppeteer

I have this function, which iterates over an episodes array and run an automate function that uses puppeteer to **scrape** over a website.

```
export const automateBulk = async (
  type: string,
  kind: string,
  slug: string
) => {
  try {
    console.log('type: ', type)
    const season = await getSeason(kind, slug)
    const data: ISeasonDownlod[] = []

    const promises = season.episodes.map(async (episode) => {
      const links = await automateSingle('episode', episode.slug.split('/')[1])
      data.push({ episode, links })
    })
    await Promise.all(promises)
    return data.sort()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error)
    throw new Error(error.message)
  }
}
```

So that `automate` function runs asynchronously for each item on that episodes array.
There is no need to wait for each automate to finish, they can run separately.

So in short I want to parallelize the execution of the automated function for each array, and then wait for all the paralyzed executions to finish then return the data array.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster can help.

Comment: This will definitely do, I will try it out, thanks.